# CruiseControl.Net Dashboard + Gendarme Plugin

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, dashboard

I try to combine CC.NET with Gendarme. I use CC.NET 1.5.
Gendarme already checks the build and generates a report.

But I can't get the dahsboard to show the report. How can I do it?

I added this in my ccnet.config:

```
<merge><files>
<file>C:\MyProjectArtefacts\gendarme-results.xml</file>     
</files></merge>
```

And that to my dashboard.config:

```
<xslFile>xsl\gendarme-summary-ccnet.xsl</xslFile>
<xslReportBuildPlugin description="Gendarme Report" actionName="GendarmeBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\gendarme-report-ccnet.xsl"/>
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors. Are you triggering Gendarme directly from CCNET or from NAnt script?

Comment: I am triggering Gendarme from CCNET.

Comment: In my Build Log I can see the Gendarme report as xml. But I don't have a Build report.

Comment: I got it!
I had to logon to the dashboard administration and install the gendarme package! 
I didn't know that.
All works fine now...